# Windows Service not retrieving edited SQL rows

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-services

I tried to find an answer to this using the search, but I feel like I am wording it poorly for decent results.

I have a windows service that uses Linq-SQL. It should pull data from a table every 20 seconds, process the data, update the row accordingly and then rinse and repeat.

```
    SQLDataContext sqlDB;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
         ServiceLog1.WriteEntry("Service1 started");

        sqlDB= new SQLDataContext ();

        //Initalize and start Timer for service action
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 20000; // 20 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.DoWork);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void DoWork(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        List<Items> items= sqlDB.Items.Where(i=> i.Processed == false).Take(20).ToList();

        if(items.Count > 0)
            ServiceLog1.WriteEntry("Processing " + items.Count + " queue items.");

         //work work...
         //set items processed == true
         //submit changes to DB
```

My issue (and I'm not even 100% sure this is an issue) is this:

If this was to run through three unprocessed test items, it would update them all to processed as it should. Simple to test a WHAT IF scenario, if I was to change the value of processed for one item back to false in SQL, the service will create an entry to the event log saying it is processing one item, but the item will never be updated again and will be processed on every loop.

This seems to only happen to items edited in SQL. New items are processed normally. Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: I'd suspect that the `SQLDataContext` is keeping modified objects in memory - What happens if you create a new context each time the timer elapses?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's exactly what it was, didn't even occur to me. If you add this as an answer I'll mark it when it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out in the question comments, my issue was related to an SQLDataContext keeping objects in memory. I needed to create a new context each time the timer elapses.